# Laravel 8: Error Call to undefined method DateTime::set() while saving record

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, php-carbon

I recently update my laravel 8 and It seems like Carbon or date request is not working properly I am getting the following error while saving the record with date time

```
exception: "Error"
file:     "/../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasAttributes.php"
line: 848
message: "Call to undefined method DateTime::set()"
```

**Controller**

```
$startDate = $request->start_date_time;
$events->start_date_time = Carbon::parse($startDate);
```

**Parsing string:**
2021-07-14T07:43:27.498Z

**Version**

PHP 7.4.21, Laravel 8

Comment: what is$request->start_date_time; value

Comment: Parsing string: 2021-07-14T07:43:27.498Z

Comment: i need to know whats the format of start_date_time in reuqest

Comment: I did not set any specific format, I just parsed the string inside the Carbon::parse function the string that I am receiving via the API request is 2021-07-14T07:43:27.498Z

Comment: 2021-07-14T07:43:27.498Z is this value is from $startDate or output of  Carbon::parse($startDate) this ?

Comment: Here is the dd result "2021-07-14T07:43:27.498Z"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234847/discussion-between-john-lobo-and-muhammad-owais).

Comment: what is your 'nesbot/carbon' version in composer.lock file?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The issue is with casts

```
'start_date_time' => 'dateTime',
'end_date_time' => 'dateTime'
```

so it should be

```
'start_date_time' => 'datetime',
'end_date_time' => 'datetime'
```

Ref:https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#attribute-casting

Answer (score 4):

Its resolved by changing my event model

**Before**

```
protected $casts = [
    'start_date_time' => 'dateTime',
    'end_date_time' => 'dateTime',
]
```

**After**

```
protected $casts = [
    'start_date_time' => 'datetime',
    'end_date_time' => 'datetime',
]
```